# that had -> having?

Tags: grammar, redundancy, editing

I want to make this sentence shorter:

> Also, items that had poor parameter estimates were removed from the analysis.

Is it correct to turn **that had** into **having**?

> Also, items having poor parameter estimates were removed from the analysis.

It doesn't sound good to me. I would appreciate it if you could give me other alternatives.

Comment: Perhaps **with**?

Comment: @medica Could **that have** or **that had** always (when have means possession) replaced by **with**? It's interesting to me :)

Comment: With is tenseless. I won't say **always**,  but generally, yes.

Comment: @EhsanAbd: It's not a matter of replacing one string with another. Any relative clause with a relative pronoun as subject, and with _have_ in its 'possess' sense as the only verb, may be converted into a participle _having_ phrase, or in most cases also may be converted into a prepositional phrase using _with_. But you're not replacing words; you're replacing **Constructions**. Words are the mortar of sentences, but constructions are the bricks.

Comment: @JohnLawler your comment really merits to be the answer. Please post it as an answer so that I tick it.  :)

Answer (score 1):

I like boh sentences contructions. 
The use of gerund sounds ok to me.

- Also items showing poor  parameters ... (Might be an alternative).

The gerund refers to a characteristic present at that specific time.

- Also items (that were) showing/ having / presenting/ poor parameters...